# Python functions - clean code

Tags: python

Quick question, I recently learned about functions. But I am a little insecure about the print option. Whats the better option for a nice code if I want to print out a result: to integrate the printoption into the function or to print the function?

Option1:

```
def is_number_in_string(string, number):
  if str(number) in string:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(def is_number_in_string(string, number)
```

---

Option2:

```
def is_number_in_string(string, number):
  if str(number) in string:
    return print("True")
  else:
    return print("False")

def is_number_in_string(string, number)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: FYI, when calling a function you don't include the `def` part.

Comment: I think this is opinion based. Personally, I prefer Option 1. Since your function name is a question, it is natural to return a boolean value (as in option 1), not a string (option 2).

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, but the first case you can use `def is_number_in_string(string, number): return str(number) in string` then call the function as `print(is_number_in_string(string, number))`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/ has a pretty good tutorial. You should work your way through it.

Comment: Just to note: you could just `return str(number) in string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning print will return `None` as print does not return anything, so option 2 will not. Also, functions are not called by putting def in front of them, that is how you define them, so neither Option 1 nor Option 2 will work.

In this case, the base way would probably be:

```
def is_number_in_string(string, number):
    return str(number) in string

print(is_number_in_string("myString84", 84))
```

Comment: Additionally, the entire thing could be boiled down to `print(str(number) in string)`, but as your question was about definitions, I have omitted it from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Function print does return None, so you should directly return True or False.

Answer (score 0):

In both the options you are not calling functions. You just defined function
You have to call function like below

```
is_number_in_string('stringarg', numberarg)
```